# Search in all objects of a NSArray of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have implemented the search method for a UITableView populate from a NSArray (mylist):

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

    // reset array
    [self.filteredListContent removeAllObjects]; 

    // check the elements contained in the list
    NSString *cellTitle;

    for (cellTitle in myList){  //CHANGE HERE

        NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame){
            [filteredListContent addObject:cellTitle];
        }
    }
}
```

Now i would the same method for search a char in `objectForKey:@"name"` of a List of `NSDictionary`:

```
myList [0]:
{
        gender
        id
        name
        picture }
myList [1]
{
        gender
        id
        name
        picture }
```

I would something like this:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope{

    [self.filteredFriendsList removeAllObjects]; 

    NSString *cellTitle;


        for (cellTitle in [[friendsList /* all objects */] objectForKey:@"name"]){

        NSComparisonResult result = [cellTitle compare:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];

        if (result == NSOrderedSame){
            [filteredFriendsList addObject:cellTitle];
        }

        }
}
```

Someone has some ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
for (NSString *name in [friendsList valueForKey:@"name"])
{
    if ([name isEqualToString:searchText]) [filteredFriendsList addObject:name];
}
```

The key here is the fact that `valueForKey:` method once invoked on an `NSArray` it calls `valueForKey:` on every of its objects.

Ps. If you want a case insensitive comparison you can do so like:

```
NSComparisonResult res = [searchTex caseInsensitiveCompare:name];
if (res == NSOrderedSame) [filteredFriendsList addObject:name];
```

**EDIT:** (To include solution for substring matching)

```
if ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location =! NSNotFound) 
{ 
    // 'name' contains 'searchText' 
}
```

Comment: You want to get all strings that would contain "L" (in your example), or just starting with an "L" ?

Comment: Hi, and thank you.
Your method works but, i want not compare the entire string, but i would make a search char to char. An example: when i click the char "L" i would see in the table every string with "L" in.
Can you help me to do this?


And after... 
When i call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and i execute this code, the app crashes:

    friendsDict = [filteredFriendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", [friendsDict objectForKey:@"name"]);

:/
I hate the tables.

Comment: I would get all strings than contain "L"

Comment: Then try this:
`if ([name rangeOfString:searchText].location =! NSNotFound) {
  // 'name' contains 'searchText'
}`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just have the method do:

```
Friend *friend;

for (friend in friendsList) {
     NSString *cellTitle = [friend objectForKey:@"name"];
     /* do comparison */
}
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't recommend declaring your iteration variable `friend` outside the loop. Worst case scenario, if `friendsList` is empty and you accidentally use `friend` outside the scope of the loop, you will crash. Better to define it like `for (Friend *friend in friendsList) { ... }`

Comment: Hi, and thank you. Your method works but, i want not compare the entire string, but I would get all strings than contain the char insert in search box. An example: when i click the char "L" i would see in the table every string with "L" in. Can you help me to do this? And after... When i call the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and i execute this code, the app crashes: friendsDict = [filteredFriendsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; NSLog(@"%@", [friendsDict objectForKey:@"name"]); :/ I hate the tables.